# What is Markovnikov's rule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology, regioselectivity, c-c-addition

What is Markovnikov's rule? How can we use it to predict the products of additions to alkenes? And is it always obeyed, or are there exceptions to this rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Markovnikov's rule is used to predict how (for example) HX, where X is a halide, adds to an unsymmetrical olefin.  As the diagram below shows, Markovnikov addition follows the rule that the "H" will add to the least substituted carbon while the "X" will add to the most substituted carbon.  This is due to the fact that these reactions proceed by protonaton of the olefin to yield a carbocation.  Protonation at the least substituted carbon yields the most stable carbocation (in this case a secondary carbocation).  Finally the carbocation reacts with $\ce{X^-}$ to yield the final product.

[image: Examples of Markovnikov and anti-Markovnikov additions]

In some cases the Markovnikov rule is not followed.  Such additions to olefins are termed "anti-Markovnikov".  These reactions typically proceed through a radical intermediate rather than a carbocation.  For example, addition to the olefin might be initiated by the addition of a bromine radical to generate the most stable radical intermediate, which would place the radical center at the most highly substituted carbon. Addition of a hydrogen radical completes the process and generates the final product which has the reverse addition pattern as compared to the Markovnikov addition product.

Comment: Wouldn’t an equally good example be $\ce{X} = \ce{BR2}$, i.e. the anti-Markovnikov addition observed with boron compounds?

Comment: @Jan Yes, hydroboration would be another good example.

Comment: The hydroboration of RCH=CH2 is a Markovnikov addition (RCH2CH2)3B. Boron is more electropositive than hydrogen just like hydrogen is more electropositive than a halogen. It is the replacement of boron with oxygen during oxidation that makes the overall reaction (alkene to alcohol) anti-Markovnikov because oxygen is more electronegative than hydrogen.  Today's use of Markovnikov's rule should be more expansive than the limited examples of the original studies. Note: Markovnikov stated that the halide added to the more substituted end of the double bond.